# DIV background color showing past edges of contained PNG image

Tags: css, png

I have a div with a red background and a `50% border-radius` that contains a circular PNG image with transparency. The red is "bleeding" past the border of the image, which I do not want. See below for a screenshot.

I've tried adjusting the padding and the width of the image.

Is there a way to prevent the background of the parent div from appearing past the edges of the contained image?

I've reproduced the issue here (note the blue appearing above the pink circle): https://codepen.io/ScribbleScratch/pen/LYzjRYN

[image: Red background appears past the edge of the PNG image]

Comment: Please can you include a code snippet so that others can reproduce?

Comment: Reproduced in codepen -- see link in the OP

Comment: What I see when I compare the two side by side in Photoshop is that the circle image is not exactly 350px. It looks 349px on the y axis. Can you confirm if this is the case?

Comment: Is there a reason that you have chosen not to mask your image with css clip-path? Then you don't need your image to be created as a circle.

Comment: I hadn't considered using clip-path, but seems like that might be the way to go.

Comment: It looks like the issue is due to the anti-aliasing of the image, which along with the transparency, is letting some of the background color through. However, although it's not as bad, the issue persists in some areas even without anti-aliasing applied. I'll try using clip-path instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your pink circle image is not 350px (I am not referring to the size that you set it in your html). Here is it illlustrated with the marquee tool set at 349px. As you can see the pink circle image does not fill the marquee selection on the y axis, there is a white space at the bottom.

So when you overlay the two you see some of the blue css behind the pink image.

[image]